# How to Move the Sliders in accordion with javaScriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to Move the Slider by DragandDropBy method, but the slider is moving to an incorrect position. I used the javascriptexecutor too, but that's also not working.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("http://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/sliders/#Color Picker");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS );

WebElement iFrame = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#post-2673 > div.twelve.columns > div.newtabs.horizontal > div > div.single_tab_div.resp-tab-content.resp-tab-content-active > p > iframe"));

String sFrameContent = iFrame.getText().toString();
System.out.println("The Iframe Content is: "+sFrameContent );

driver.switchTo().frame(iFrame);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);

WebElement redSlider = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#red > div"));

Thread.sleep(1000);

action.clickAndHold(redSlider).moveByOffset(90,0).release(redSlider).release().build().perform();

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

jse.executeScript("document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].style.left = '10.000%' ");
System.out.println("-------END--------");

driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

This code is not giving any errors while executing but the Slider is not moving to the right position correctly.

```html
<body class="ui-widget-content" style="border:0;">
  <p class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="padding:4px;">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil" style="float:left; margin:-2px 5px 0 0;"></span> Simple Colorpicker
  </p>
  <div id="red" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-min" style="width: 9.80392%;"></div><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 9.80392%;"></span></div>
  <div id="green" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-min" style="width: 54.902%;"></div><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 54.902%;"></span></div>
  <div id="blue" class="ui-slider ui-corner-all ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <div class="ui-slider-range ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-slider-range-min" style="width: 23.5294%;"></div><span tabindex="0" class="ui-slider-handle ui-corner-all ui-state-default" style="left: 23.5294%;"></span></div>
  <div id="swatch" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="background-color: rgb(25, 140, 60);"></div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should work for you (add all):

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('red').getElementsByTagName('div')[0].setAttribute('style', 'width: 50%;')");
    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('red').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].setAttribute('style', 'left: 50%;')");
```

**UPDATE:-**

YOU CAN USE FOLLOWING ALSO :

```
    WebElement spanButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#red > div+span"));

            Actions action = new Actions(driver);

            action.clickAndHold(spanButton).moveByOffset(-20,0).release(spanButton).build().perform(); // to move slider backward

action.clickAndHold(spanButton).moveByOffset(20,0).release(spanButton).build().perform(); // to move slider forward
```

Comment: This may work but this is not a user scenario and may shortcut around other `onclick` behaviors. You'd be better off actually clicking the element.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid JSE-type answers because they are not user scenarios. No user is going to set the slider using JS, they are going to click the slider. Since clicking the slider is something you'll likely want to do more than once in testing, I would write it into a function. See below

```
public static void setRed(int percentage)
{
    driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.demo-frame")));
    WebElement red = new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("red")));
    Dimension d = red.getSize();
    new Actions(driver).moveToElement(red, d.width * percentage / 100, d.height / 2).click().build().perform();
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

and call it like

```
driver.get("http://www.globalsqa.com/demo-site/sliders/#Color Picker");
setRed(25);
```

You'd probably want to do some error checking on the percentage passed into the function and make sure it's between 0-100 just to be safe.